# How can I match subdomains in a solr search?

Tags: solr, lucene

I can found domains using ClassicAnalyzer.

Given a doc with a domain like facebook.com, what is the best approach to match queries like

- faceboook.com (obvious)
- xyz.facebook.com
- abc.xyz.facebook.com
- facebook

Any combination of analyzers (tokenizers, filters...) or approches to build my own will be welcomed.

Thx!

Comment: So, if you search for `facebook` you also want to match `xyz.facebook.com`. But if you search for `xyz` you do **not** want to match `xyz.facebook.com`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using a [PatternCaptureGroupFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory) with a pattern like ([a-zA-Z\-_0-9]+)

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case StandardTokenizer helps better. It Preserves Internet domain names and email addresses as a single token. it helps if you post an example document and few search terms that you would like to match.

**Update:** Look at text_general field type , that does exactly what you are looking for. I ran analysis for xyz.facebook.com,faceboook.com,abc.xyz.facebook.com and facebook and it kept each of them together and matched the way you wanted.

Comment: StandardTokenizer as in solr 4.6 do not detect HOST type tokens (for instance a domain). Only ClassicTokenizer or UAX29Tokenizer do.